# cakephp3 how to share one coreto multiple sites

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

well , I want to use only one cake's core for multiple sites.

but I modify the paths.php and it doesn't work

it still load all the scripts in the website's directory

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the question isn't precise enough.
If you simply want many websites with one vendor dir, put it somewhere and symlink it... :-)

**If you plan to use a unique Model&Controller set for many websites :**

Notes:
*Achieved with Composer

Useful if you want to use 1 cake3 Core and 1 models/controllers set

This worked for me ([source](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/fr/development/configuration.html#additional-class-paths)), and obviously depends on your expectations.*

---

Create a new folder to store classes, eg. resources, into app folder

Put Controller folder inside it (but you could do the same with Model)

Edit 'composer.json' in that way:

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Controller\\": "/vagrant/app/resources/Controller",
        "App\\": "src"
    }
```

Don't forget a little bit of this to ensure autoloader is updated:

```
composer update
```

Next step if needed, check [Official doc](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/fr/development/configuration.html#les-chemins-de-view-et-de-plugin) for View, there's another way to achieve it.